# Self controlled android?

Tags: android, python, remote-server

Can android be self-controlled. I know you can control it with ADB.

Do the apps like "3cx droid desktop" or "remote web desktop full" use this feature to control it?

I want to control my android phone over the internet and i don't have a public IP address, so I tried those two apps and their "bridge mode", which probably transfers data through their server, but just the remote control feature (alongside with camera, which works) cannot be running in the bridge mode.

So is there any way you can control a phone with commands from e.g. Twitter? It would simulate the touch itself? (actually the only thing I want is what I mean by remote control - to simulate the touches, only x,y coordinates). I know python basics. So far no java.